# SAS, ROC curve, PROC LOGISITC, point labels

Tags: sas, label, proc, roc

I am trying to create a single ROC curve for three bio-markers on a common population. 
I have already created an overlay curve from proc logistic statement. is there any way in SAS (among default options) to label the specific points on one of the bio-markers. 
also, I would like to create a horizontal and vertical lines that depict the Sn and 1-Sp for those specific points.

is there an easier way to do this other than creating a annotation dataset and plotting a graph through proc gplot?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I find proc sgplot much more intuitive than gplot.

Answer (score 0):

*Among default options*, the answer is no. SAS gives you options to control certain aspects of the ROC curves in the `roc` and `rocoptions` options in the `proc logistic` statement, but it doesn't support adding specific features to plots directly within the procedure.

To get the features you're looking for, as you said, you'll need to plot the raw ROC data using a graphics procedure. I like `sgplot`, the ODS graphics successor to `gplot`. Assuming you know exactly which points you want to label ahead of time, horizontal and vertical lines for the sensitivity and 1 - specificity can be generated using the `refline` statement in `sgplot`.

An annotation dataset may be the best way to go to label specific points. If you're using `sgplot`, you can generate an SG annotation dataset using the SG annotation macros. More information regarding SG annotation, including the use of the macros, can be found [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/67924/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wi4yti5mcg06n1ss0onifod94t.htm). The macros are located in the default SAS autocall macro library so they should be able to be referenced without any special fussing. Once you have your dataset, you can feed it into `sgplot` using the `sganno=` option in the `proc sgplot` statement.